# How to display data with a ManyToMany relation and a joint table?

Tags: symfony, collections, twig, many-to-many, relation

i'm currently working on a symfony project and i have a problem.

This project is a website about a theater. There is therefore an "actors" entity and a "shows" entity.
Each show can have multiple comedians, and comedians can have multiple shows. So I generated a ManyToMany relationship, and got a "spectacles.actors" link table.
I don't understand how I can display in my twig, for each actor, the shows in which he is present.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwaZA.png)

I tried

```
{{ actors.spectacles.title }}
```

but its not working, i also tried a double for loop, but still not working. Can you help me please?

Thank you

---

Ok it doesn't work but I found why. In fact with my ManyToMany relationship, I got two binding tables: actors_spectacles and spectacles_actors. When I perform my fixtures, the spectacles_actors table is filled but not actor_spectacles.

But how to fill it? Since there is a certain order in fixtures, I am having a lot of trouble understanding how fixtures work with ManyToMany relationship, can you help me?

[image: click here to see the tables manager]

Comment: You are not supposed to have two intermediate tables. Maybe you should check your annotation but before read this article: https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/doctrine-relations/many-to-many
Symfonycasts is one of the best resource to learn Symfony

Answer (score 1):

You should loop over each actor and each linked shows to the actor.

Let's say you fetched all the actors in your controller:

```
{% for actor in actors %}
<ul>
    {% for spectacle in actor.spectacles %}
        <li>{{ spectacle.title }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endfor %}
```

ps: I advise you to use singular form for naming your entities ;)